# calling sharedpreference value from onTabSelected method

Tags: android, tabs, sharedpreferences

I am using actionbar tabs (deprecated) to test some tab features. I want to save form validation information from my 1st tab to shared preferences, then on the onTabSelected method, check the value before switching to the next tab. My current problem is checking the value saved in sharedpreferences from the tablistener class

Tab1:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;



public class clientFragmentTab extends Fragment {


ArrayList<String> saleRecord;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
EditText currDate, invoiceNo , vehicle;
Spinner clientName, territory;
String spinnerValue;
ShowAlert alert;


View rootView = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.client_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    currDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    clientName = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    invoiceNo = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    vehicle = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    territory = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    currDate.setText(formattedDate);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Select Client");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");
    list.add("Item 4");
    list.add("Item 5");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item , list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    clientName.setAdapter(adapter);

    clientName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            spinnerValue = clientName.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
            edt.putString("client_valid", spinnerValue);
            edt.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spinnerValue = "Nothing";
            SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
            edt.putString("client_valid", spinnerValue);
            edt.commit();

        }
    });

}
}
```

TabListener:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;



public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private Fragment fragment;




// The contructor
public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment)
{
    this.fragment = fragment;

}



// When a tab is tapped, the FragmentTransaction replaces
// the content of our main layout with the specified fragment;
// that's why we declared an id for the main layout.
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(clientFragmentTab.getActivity());
    String id = sp.getString("client_valid", "empty");

    if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);


    }
    else if(tab.getPosition() == 1)
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    }
    else if(tab.getPosition() == 2)
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    }
}

// When a tab is unselected, we have to hide it from the user's view.
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

// Nothing special here. Fragments already did the job.
@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

}
```

Comment: you get any error? Log?

Comment: Yes. What is the problem you are facing? Logcat error? Is it a nullpointer exception?

Comment: In my IDE, i'm getting an error non-static method getActivity cannot be referenced in a static context. I had tried variations like: SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());